# Updating parent's object data from child controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a object $scope.object in parentCtrl, and I have a isolated scope directive. Inside directive, I have a functionality wherein I need to make an API call and fetch one of the property of $scope.object (this property is an array of object) and replace this property in original $scope.object.

I have tried various ways of doing it but somehow I am not exactly getting at it. I have tried updating it using $scope.$parent.object from directive's controller.
After this I tried sending the fetched array in to the parent's controller and replacing it there.

Once the $scope.object gets updated, the directive should run as the directive's template is binded with properties of $scope.object. 
The interesting thing is that the view gets updated with new data but the data in original object somehow again becomes null.

I guess, there is some issue with the way my directive is called as the same directive is called nestedly. As shown below:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in A" ng-if="t.selected">
 <div directive> <div>
</li>
```

where, A is the fetched property and t.selected is true. Now in the fetched data t.selected is true for two elements of array, while the directive is called 4 times, twice for each element. In the first iteration the data remains intact in parent object, while in 2nd iteration, data becomes null

I want to know, how do I update the data of parent object permanently

Directive:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, t) in fetch.data>
       <div layout="row" layout-wrap directive  target="t" ></div>

</li>
```

and this target is double way binded in directive's scope with parent's scope

Comment: how is `directive` defined? you said it is an "isolated scope directive", but if it is able to know what `t` is when declared the way you are showing right now, it's definitely not isolated...

Comment: updated, the directive has a double way binding with few variables in parent's scope

Comment: that's not the code for the directive, that's just an updated way of expressing the previous code.  I was specifically asking about the JavaScript. Though I doubt that this would work the way you intend anyway, as it seems that you are trying to iterate over object properties, not array values, which will most definitely not be writable by the directive.